# How to turn cell yellow if date in cell is between 180 and 365 days in the past

Tags: google-sheets, date, conditional-formatting

In Google Spreadsheets how do I use conditional formatting to turn a cell yellow if the date is between 180 and 365 days in the past?

Answer (score 1):

Please try a Custom formula is like so:

```
=and(A1>today()-365,A1<today()-180)
```

which may be applied not just to A1 but say to the whole of ColumnA if the Range: is `A:A`.

Comment: Thank you so much! In conjunction with this formula, how would I make the cell a certain color if it was empty? No date entered?

Comment: Thanks again, as you can tell I"m new to custom formulas. Would you be able to recommend a site that would help me learn all the rules for these formulas? Like how to change the order of the custom formulas?

Comment: Thanks again, I'm trying to figure out how I can learn all the rules for custom formulas for google spreadsheets. Here's what I'm trying to do and am so close but it doesn't quite work.

Comment: If cell is empty, turn the cell blue.
If date is less than 180 days in the past, turn the cell green.
If date is between 180 and 365 days in the past, turn the cell yellow.
If date if 365 days or more in the past, turn the cell red.